# How do I use Training Phrases in DialogFlow

Tags: dialogflow-es

My Training Phrases do not seem to work in DialogFlow
What I did was I added training phrases for the chatbot. After adding the phrases, I save the intent then try it out on the chatbot. When I type in any of the phrases, it just goes to the fallback intent. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image: This image shows a screenshot of the training phrases i've added]

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You indicate they "do not seem to work", but you haven't indicated what happens when you try, how you try, or what makes you believe that it doesn't work. Updating your question with examples of what is happening may help us help you - the more you can provide, the better our chances are of finding the issue. See "[ask] a Good Question?"